# angular formly button custom type

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-formly

I am new to angular formly. I want to create a custom template for a button. code snippten given below for reference.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="button.html">
    <md-button class={{to.class}} ng-click={{to.method}}>{{to.label}}</md-button>
</script>
```

Problem is formly gives me an error while processing the ng-click directive, since directive `{{to.method}}` has not been evaluated yet.

Is it not possible to do something like this? None of the angular formly examples is making button as a template, is it conceptually wrong to do this in formly?

EDIT:

Below are the corresponding custom template and JSON:

I have created a custom template for button as:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="button.html">
    <md-button class={{to.class}} ng-click="{{to.method}}">{{to.label}}</md-button>
</script>
```

and corresponding JSON is as:

```
{
type: 'button',
templateOptions: {
   label: 'Create Item',
   class: 'md-raised md-primary',
   method: 'createItem'
}
```

Exact error is follows:

> **Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{to.method}}] starting at [{to.method}}].**

Comment: where you defined the object `to`. Post you full code. If possible post some fiddle link to get faster results for your problem.

Comment: @StarkButtowski I have added code in Question. Please check it.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue, and here is what I did to solve it. Posting for others that may have the same issue, since documentation on buttons seems to be minimal.

*Note: You don't need curly braces on angular attributes*

Setting the type:

```js
formlyConfig.setType({
  name: 'button',
  template: '<button class="{{to.class}}" ng-click="to.method()">{{to.label}}</button>'
});
```

Then where you're adding it into your form:

```js
{
  key: 'myBtn',
  type: 'button',
  templateOptions: {
    class: 'btn-primary',
    label: 'My Test Button',
    method: function() {
     alert('test');
     console.log('test');
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers!